# replace wp_get_attachment_image with my own function

Tags: images

How can I replace wp_get_attachment_image() function without changing the core files. The function doesnt have an action hook or a filter hook.

**What I am trying to achieve:**

for lazyload plugin output the image html like this:

```
<img width="150" height="150" data-src="http://localhost/yxz/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/calliope.slide_-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="calliope.slide" src="http://localhost/yxz/wp-content/uploads/blank.png">
```

instead of this:

```
<img width="150" height="150" src="http://localhost/yxz/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/calliope.slide_-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="calliope.slide">
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a filter, [`wp_get_attachment_image_attributes`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/media.php#L565), for the image attributes-- a well designed one too.

```
function alter_att_attributes_wpse_102079($attr) {
  $attr['data-src'] = $attr['src'];
  return $attr;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'alter_att_attributes_wpse_102079');
```

That will add the `data-src` attribute. That looks like what you need. You could add more attributes, or alter the existing onese, if you need.

Comment: thanks so much!! I edited the code like this to replace the src with my image:

function alter_att_attributes_wpse_102079($attr) {
  $attr['data-src'] = $attr['src'];
   $attr['src'] = 'http://i.imgur.com/xTWRCpu.png'; 
  return $attr;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'alter_att_attributes_wpse_102079');

Comment: Thank you! Still works perfectly, and good for adding alt attributes on images, where the alt is not filled out.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another function in your `functions.php` file and then use it instead of `wp_get_attachment_image()`.